# technology about native ads for inmobi

Tags: native, ads, inmobi

As we all know, native ads is the future of mobile ads, and I know inmobi has an important technology about materials matching for native ads from some article. But I can’t get any details through search engine, so anyone can give me some suggest about this technology, anything is okay, thank you very much.

Comment: Hey there. I work at InMobi. Apologies for seeing this late. 
Here is the documentation for integrating InMobi Native Ads on Android: https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/integrating-with-inmobi/inmobi-native-content-ads/

let me know if you need help with this. Thanks!

Comment: You can write to developer at inmobi dot com for any queries.